# Is it possible to server-side render jQuery with ReactJS.Net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, reactjs, reactjs.net

I've been going through [this tutorial](http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) on [ReactJS.NET](http://reactjs.net), and hit a snag. It mentions that:

> We will use simple polling here but you could easily use SignalR or other technologies.

While this works when I do client-side rendering, it throws the following error when rendering server-side. Currently, I don't actually *need* jQuery or SignalR to render the initial state as I'm only using them to subscribe to updates once the app is running. I guess my question is, what is the correct way to structure my React application so that I can render it server-side or client-side at will.

[image: An exception of type 'React.Exceptions.ReactScriptLoadException' occurred in React.dll but was not handled in user code]

Error while loading "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js": ReferenceError: **window is not defined**

Comment: why would you want to use a client-side dom library like jQuery on the server? am i missing something?

Comment: I don't... but I'm not sure how to decouple it. I think I figured it out... testing my theory.

Comment: A future release of SignalR will remove the jQuery dependency which should make it much easier to reuse. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372

Comment: I wouldn't hold your breath @DanielLoNigro unless you're submitting a pull request for it. That issue is from 2012

Comment: @daniellmb Last I heard they're working on it for the version of SignalR that will be part of ASP.NET 5. That issue was closed because they're moving it to a repo under the aspnet Github organisation.

Comment: @DanielLoNigro Right, they created the new repo ten months ago and haven't touched it yet. https://github.com/aspnet/signalr-client-js Don't get me wrong, I'd love to see this happen but I wouldn't count on it happening soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working ([live demo](https://reactpe.apphb.com)), I just needed to move the call to `React.render` outside of the jsx file and pass in what I needed (see snippet below). Another option would be to try and mock the expected objects with [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

```
<!-- Render the React Component Server-Side -->
@Html.React("CommentBox", new
{
  data = Model,
  conn = false
})

<!-- Optionally Render the React Component Client-Side -->
@section scripts {
  <script src="~/Scripts/react/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/comments")
  <script>
    React.render(React.createElement(CommentBox, {
      data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
      conn: $.hubConnection()
    }), document.getElementById("react1"));
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery while rendering server side using reactjs.net:

The answer is a partial Yes if you put the jQuery in the ComponentDidMount function of React with your setup above.

Like this:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    if (this.props.userID == 0){
        $("#postButton").hide();
    }
}
```

It also worked in some other places but not everywhere. Other places in the React script, I got "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Here's some additional comments by the reactjs.net author himself. Basically, jQuery is not designed to work server side so prob best not to rely on it.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/3y8gfgqJNq4

As an alternative, for instance, if you want to control the visibility of an element without using jQuery, you can create a style and then assign the style based on If logic. Then add the style as an inline attribute to the element as shown below. This should work fine in React.

```
var styleComment = {display: 'block'};

if (this.props.commentCount == 0){
    styleComment = {display: 'none'}
}

<div style={styleComment}>Count is greater than 0</div>
```